Delete DB entry for type text[] from PreparedStatement
our postgres DB define entry column as data type text[]
Some DB entries are as below
And now we want to delete DB entry based on Provider and Content



Provider
Content




A
{abcd}


B
{abcde}



SQL statement works fine with
delete from entries where provider_id = 'A' and content = '{abcd}'

But when I tried to use PreparedStatement in Java, the sql.Array value cannot be set to content
    protected static final String DELETE_INVALID_ENTRY_STATEMENT = 
        "delete from entries where provider_id = ? and content = ?";

    val stmt = conn.prepareStatement(DELETE_INVALID_ENTRY_STATEMENT)
    stmt.setString(1, entry.getProvider());
    val body = conn.createArrayOf(TEXT_DATA_TYPE, new String[]{entry.getBody()});
    stmt.setArray(2, body);
    stmt.executeUpdate();

From the log, I can see the body already set to
{abcd}
But stmt is as below that content is still ?
SQL query is delete from entries where provider_id = 'A' and content = ?
Wondering why content cannot be set with correct value

This code wouldn't even compile; you should be using .setArray. Please update the code to be what you actually have; it doesn't make sense to say that non-compiling code would have 'content is still ?'.

Sorry that I typed the wrong code that it is .setArray and updated the question

From the code in your question: val stmt = conn.prepareStatement(DELETE_INVALID_ENTRY_STATEMENT) Shouldn't that be var (and not val) ?

val is from package lombok
https://projectlombok.org/features/val

Can you add full text of error?
